# Deploying Google Analytics original snippet and Tag manager GA in one page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a situation in which a page already contains the Google Analytics snippet which sends data to one account (not mine).

I have inserted the Google Tag Manager snippet with Google Analytics on it with a second tracking number of a different account.

But the second Google Analytics, deployed via Google Tag Manager, is not receiving any data.

Everything looks like it's set correctly, What is the cause of the problem?
Can there be some conflict between the original Google Analytics snippet and the one deployed via Google Tag Manager?

Comment: are you using thes global vars recommended from the doc like `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` ? Hwat about to clear that before second use like `_gaq = [];` in order to have an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the container of GTM has been published or not. If it is not the 'Google Analytics' tag from GTM is not being fired on the page.

You can preview the container and see for the 'Google Analytics' call being made via Omnibug

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the default Tag for sending Pageview data to Google Analytics and then Publish these changes. Verify they work in your GA Real Time Tool. The other GA tag shouldn't matter to you.

[image: Default Tag]

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tag Manager team you can and should use both the new analytics.js and GTM tags when transitioning to Tag Manager, using different property IDs.

Once you've tested the GTM setup is working properly you can then remove the analytics.js code.

See this video for details - https://youtu.be/XBCNJo9qGH8

Could it be that you're using the old GA library? If so just update to analytics.js and try again.